# Vue-Howler (Howler.js) and mobile browser lockscreen controls

Tags: nuxt.js, howler.js

I have a player setup on a Nuxt.js website with Vue-Howler package, that has the navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler function that should set up the pause button on the lock screen of the mobile browsers, that is triggered from the Nuxt/Vue playEpisode() method on a button

```js
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', () => {
    this.togglePlayback()
})
```

As far as showing the pause button it works, but it doesn't trigger pausing the audio itself.
Any idea what could be wrong, how should this be setup correctly?

Comment: Do you have any error anywhere? Some info via the devtools?

Comment: No errors as far as I know. The play/pause trigger works fine in the component itself